# How to iterate through a function in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

On one sheet I have a table of statistics similar to this:

```
  A         B     C     D
1 Teams     MP    GF    GA
2 Team A    3     3     2
3 Team B    2     1     3
4 Team C    3     5     2
5 Team D    2     2     1
```

I then have some formulas that calculate an expected score between two teams set up like this:

```
  A        B                                               C              D              E
7 Teams    GF/G                                            GA/G           Avg            Exp Score
8 Team 1  =VLOOKUP(A8,$A$1:$D$5,3)/VLOOKUP(A8,$A$1:$D$5,2) =VLOOKUP(...)  =AVERAGE(...)  =B8-C9+D8
9 Team 2  =VLOOKUP(...)                                    =VLOOKUP(...)  =AVERAGE(...)  =B9-C8+D9
```

I then have a separate sheet that has the matchups between teams like this:

```
  A       B        C
1 Date    Matchup  Exp Score
2 11/15   Team D   =FORMULA(
3 11/15   Team B   =FORMULA(
4 11/16   Team C   =FORMULA(
5 11/16   Team A   =FORMULA(
6 11/17   Team B   =FORMULA(
7 11/17   Team C   =FORMULA(
8 11/17   Team D   =FORMULA(
9 11/17   Team A   =FORMULA(
```

My question is if there is some kind of formula that can take the teams in the matchup, copy and paste them behind the scenes into cells A8 and A9, and spit out the Exp Score that would generate in E8 and E9. Is this something that is possible to do in Google Sheets or does it have to be manually copied and pasted into the cells and then copy and paste the results to where I want them?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: I am not sure how to do this

Comment: do: https://i.imgur.com/G1RJKlg.png ...then: https://i.imgur.com/8paTFUz.png and paste here the url

Comment: Conner, can you provide the formula you are using for your average in column D, from your second image above?  That might also provide the missing info to propose an answer.

Comment: =AVERAGE($C$2:$C$5)

Comment: Hi ! Could be clearer on what is your expected output? Do you want to take all the Teams from your Match up sheet and paste then into ```A8``` and ```A9``` being these cells therefore ```Team 1, Team 2, etc...```? If you could illustrate your question with your actual vs expected output it could help clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I've put your formulas together, and come up with the following result, but I think possibly your logic for the average is a little bit off.
Should it not be:

```
=SUM(C2:C5) / SUM(B2:B5) /2
```

So the sum of all the goals scored divided by the total number of matches (number of times any team played divided by 2)?  This gives the averages goals per game, and then your other formulas add a positive delta to the team with the stronger GF/G, and a negative delta to the team with the weaker GF/G.

Also, your data may not be valid.  Shouldn't the total number of goals scored BY all teams, also equal the total number of goals scored AGAINST all teams?  So the sum of column C must equal the sum of column D?  I therefore changed the numbers in column D slightly.

The result then for your data looks like this:
[image]

where the formula in E1 is:

```
=ArrayFormula({"GF/G";C2:C5/$B2:$B5})
```

and in G1 is:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Avg Goals/G";SUM($C$2:$C$5) / (SUM(B2:B5)/2) })
```

Adding in your matchups and projected scores, I get this:
[image]

where the projected scores for all the teams in column I are given by this formula, in K2:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(I2:I7,$A$2:$G$5,5)
            - vlookup(J2:J7,$A$2:$G$5,5) 
            + $G$2/2)
```

Note that I've duplicated columns K:M in columns N:P, but shown with a decimal place to show the average goals per game still equals 2.2, but with rounding adjustments (no fractions of a goal) it doesn't always work out right.

Here is [my sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qyfnYT28aXXbGS3RaQSxhffV3G9m_dW-dqDH4SnT6JY/edit?usp=sharing).